# Display Object data if parameters not defined

Tags: php

So let's say I want to display name inside object, That would be

```
echo $object->name
```

If I want to display age of specific person, that would be

```
echo $object->name->dave->age
```

And I can display a lot of things.

However, What should I do if I don't know parameters which to display?

So let's say `dave` passed to me, and right now in  `$person`

That would be something like

```
echo $object->name->$person->age
```

However I can't do that.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Need more detail, your question is not clear.

Comment: `$object->name->age`  makes no sense. Are you fetching the age of the name? If you want that format  then `name` needs to be an object with a `__toString()` function that returns the name if it is cast as a string. The `name`-object would also need to have an `age`-property. A more sensible structure would be to have `$obj->name` and then `$obj->age`.

Comment: Define a magic `__get` method on your classes. See http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get and more generally http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Nah, if you have `$object->name->dave`, then you are seriously doing OO wrong …

Comment: @04FS That's what I'm getting from API to my request.